# How do I backup my Ubuntu Phone?

Tags: ubuntu-touch

How do I backup my Ubuntu Phone so I can restore it to the same state after a factory reset? To specify, I'm looking for the following:

- Backup configuration
- Backup apps
- Backup app configuration
- Backup files

Copying the `/home/phablet/` folder will save the files, but does this also save all the config files and programs?

Comment: Backing up `/home/phablet` will backup everything except the apps which are in a number of places including `/opt/click.ubuntu.com/` and `/usr/share/click/preinstalled`. However even backing up those directories won't be enough. Installing applications will unpack files in `/opt` but will also trigger other things like apparmor profile processing.

Comment: @popey So it seems the best method is to backup /home/phablet and reinstall apps after restoring a backup? All the applications configuration (i.E. tasks in the task app) should still be there if I understood you correctly? Thanks for the answer(/comment)!

Comment: Yes, all config and app data will be in your home. You can run "click list" to see a list of all apps installed, which could be a useful thing to backup.

Comment: Is it necessary to backup the .cache folder, does it have any benefits? Thx!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I made a little script to make backing up the phone easier. It's on github.

https://github.com/popey/buds

Answer (score 5):

- Backing up the `/home/phablet` folder will backup everything except the apps.
- You can get a list of all installed apps by running `click list` on your phone. You will have to reinstall these manually.

*Apps are installed in an number of places and trigger other things like apparmor profile processing so there is no easy way to backup those.*

Source: [comment by @popey](https://askubuntu.com/questions/602850/how-do-i-backup-my-ubuntu-phone?noredirect=1#comment841901_602850)