# Ubuntu Touch - Backup

Tags: ubuntu-touch, backup

Is there a way I can backup my Ubuntu phone and/or tablet (either a one off or periodically), like there is with my Ubuntu laptop? I am looking for something like rsynk or freefilesync. I personally use rsync on my laptop and find it to be great. I have had a look, but cannot find anything like that available for the phones and tablets.

Answer (score 1):

I have been looking into this myself and as yet, I cannot fond an app that can do a full system backup/restore, like the laptop ones you have mentioned. Smartphones by their nature are intended to function differently from desktops/laptops. They store a lot of their data in the cloud (contacts, emails, photos and such like). However, this will not cover sms's, photos not uploaded to the cloud and such like. For this I would suggest archiving /home/phablet. The following link may be of use to read, but this only covers a manual backup. It is not the app you are lookig for.

[How do I backup my Ubuntu Phone?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/602850/how-do-i-backup-my-ubuntu-phone)

Comment: I will be watching this as I am keep to know. I have a big hdd, just waiting for lots of backup files.

Comment: At the momeny I have been unable to find any Ubuntu Touch backup tools.so I have been talking to a developer friend of mine anf i may be looking at creating a very simple app. Any comments or thoughts would be great.