# How can an image of an Ubuntu phone be taken?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, android, aquaris, disk-image

I want to take a full image of everything on my Aquaris E4.5 Ubuntu phone such that, following a complete factory reset or reflash of the phone, that full image can be restored completely on the phone.

How can this be done?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I backup my Ubuntu Phone?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/602850/how-do-i-backup-my-ubuntu-phone)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Backup everything in `/home/phablet`. This will backup all user data and program settings. You will however need to reinstall your programs after a factory reset. But once you restore that folder, any programs installed will have the same settings as before.

Don't forget to backup all hidden folders as well, such as `/home/phablet/.config`

Comment: Ah, excellent; this is straightforward. Thanks!

Comment: Yhis is where a simple back up tool for Ubuntu Touch would come in handy. I have been looking at one but at the moment it is just plans on paper. Hopefully these plans will lead to something more solid.

Comment: @PhilUK I don't have one to play on, but I imagine you can also run an SSH server on one, and then remote into the phone, mount an NFS share and do backups this way, over WiFi.  Wouldn't be the fastest but it could work I think.